# Sticky sidebar with active state, scroll snap and drag to scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sass

Currently, I have this task of creating a section on my project. The following are the criteria of what should be done.

- When user scrolls over the section the sidebar element inside the section becomes sticky.
- Upon scrolling the sidebar active list items will have an active state depends on the what the left content is being scrolled.
- It needs to have a scroll snap effect (same as tiktok or instagram reels functionality where when user do a scroll it directly displays the next section).
- It also needs to have a drag to scroll functionality on the left content so when user drag the content upwards or downwards it goes to the next or previous element

Currently, my structure here is using a position sticky with the sidebar for sticky functionality, and have a scroll snap CSS to achieve the scroll snap goal. I am having a hard time how to implement it together with the drag to scroll and active state functionality.

I am expecting that the following functionalities will have one script or solution that will achieve the following DOD.

Here is a sample of my codepen but the position sticky is not working here maybe because of some overflow hidden on codepen itself

**Code Snippet** from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/John-Clark-Semblante/pen/MWxgvZE)

```css
.other {
  background: black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  &.red {
    background: red;
  }
  &.blue {
    background: blue;
  }
  &.yellow {
    background: yellow;
  }
  &.orange {
    background: orange;
  }
}

.column {
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  &--sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
  }
  &--content {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="other red"></section>
<section class="other blue "></section>
<section class="other yellow"></section>
<section class="scroll-on">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="column column--sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-item">Content 1</div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">Content 2</div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">Content 3</div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">Content 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column column--content">
      <!-- Start Content 1 -->
      <div class="content-item">
        <h2>Content 1</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac volutpat neque, et volutpat libero. Sed luctus justo in aliquam gravida. Ut accumsan nisi at laoreet vehicula. Vestibulum elementum, lectus sed consequat iaculis, nunc mi gravida metus,
        nec bibendum ante nulla vitae augue. Integer id quam metus. Mauris non rhoncus ante, ut laoreet nisi. Ut pretium odio ac lectus congue convallis. Donec et elementum purus. Suspendisse posuere justo ac tempus convallis. Mauris justo elit, consectetur
        sit amet purus eget, gravida fringilla neque. Quisque gravida facilisis diam et suscipit. Pellentesque eu malesuada orci. In In ex urna, luctus sed nulla eget, sodales venenatis turpis. Nulla condimentum lobortis lectus vitae ultricies. Proin
        ac mollis erat. Pellentesque sit amet nunc a velit ultricies rhoncus. Aliquam tincidunt dictum erat, quis aliquam arcu ullamcorper eget. Fusce elit leo, pellentesque sed lacus
      </div>
      <!-- End Content 1 -->

      <!-- Start Content 2 -->
      <div class="column-item">
        <h2>Content 2</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac volutpat neque, et volutpat libero. Sed luctus justo in aliquam gravida. Ut accumsan nisi at laoreet vehicula. Vestibulum elementum, lectus sed consequat iaculis, nunc mi gravida metus,
        nec bibendum ante nulla vitae augue. Integer id quam metus. Mauris non rhoncus ante, ut laoreet nisi. Ut pretium odio ac lectus congue convallis. Donec et elementum purus. Suspendisse posuere justo ac tempus convallis. Mauris justo elit, consectetur
        sit amet purus eget, gravida fringilla neque. Quisque gravida facilisis diam et suscipit. Pellentesque eu malesuada orci. In
      </div>
      <!-- End Content 2 -->

      <!-- Start Content 3 -->
      <div class="column-item">
        <h2>Content 3</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac volutpat neque, et volutpat libero. Sed luctus justo in aliquam gravida. Ut accumsan nisi at laoreet vehicula. Vestibulum elementum, lectus sed consequat iaculis, nunc mi gravida metus,
        nec bibendum ante nulla vitae augue. Integer id quam metus. Mauris non rhoncus ante, ut laoreet nisi. Ut pretium odio ac lectus congue convallis. Donec et elementum purus. Suspendisse posuere justo ac tempus convallis. Mauris justo elit, consectetur
        sit amet purus eget, gravida fringilla neque. Quisque gravida facilisis diam et suscipit. Pellentesque eu malesuada orci. In placerat enim pellentesque at. Maecenas urna mauris, feugiat at sapien non, tempor tincidunt eros. Praesent consectetur
        a dui sit amet lacinia.
      </div>
      <!-- End Content 3 -->

      <!-- Start Content 4 -->
      <div class="column-item">
        <h2>Content 4</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac volutpat neque, et volutpat libero. Sed luctus justo in aliquam gravida. Ut accumsan nisi at , lectus sed consequatlaoreet vehicula. Vestibulum elementum, lectus sed consequat iaculis, nunc
        mi gravida metus, nec bibendum ante nulla vitae augue. Integer id quam metus. Mauris non rhoncus ante, ut laoreet nisi. Ut pretium odio ac lectullamcorper eget. Fusce elit leo, pellentesque sed lacus vel, efficitur malesuada lorem. Cras commodo
        justo a erat imperdiet bibendum. Vestibulum ante augue, placerat eget metus nec, elementum posuere est. Ut tempor lorem purus, ut molestie libero rutrum vitae. Quisque auctor, odio nec euismod varius, eros purus finibus diam, sit amet iaculis
        purus ante eu nisi. Vivamus a lorem orci. Proin mattis dui sit amet metus suscipit molestie. Proin elementum bibendum nibh, ut volutpat orci commodo ut. Donec eleifend tempor urna, id egestas magna consectetur eu. Morbi ut feugiat velit. Etiam
        a vestibulum elit. Maecenas eget lorem sagittis, pulvinar risus faucibus, luctus purus. Morbi sit amet dictum neque. Integer diam sapien, finibus eget est sit amet, consequat porttitor ante. Nam feugiat metus nec nunc vulputate euismod. Quisque
        aliquam diam at lectus pulvinar, vitae consequat metus mollis. Proin ullamcorper, quam at iaculis tempor, felis tortor faucibus enim, pellentesque fringilla dolor magna ullamcorper urna. Pellentesque pretium orci mi, egeus congue convallis. Donec
        et elementum purus. Suspendisse posuere justo ac tempus convallis. Mauris justo elit, consectetur sit amet purus eget, gravida fringilla neque. Quisque gravida facilisis diam et suscipit. Pellentesque eu malesuada orci. In
      </div>
      <!-- End Content 4 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="other"></section>
<section class="other orange"></section>
<section class="other"></section>
```